# Echo php into google map javascript

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, google-maps

Is it possible (and if so please explain how) to echo php into javascript, specifically for my purpose I am trying to echo the input of a custom field from the wordpress platform into the description of a google map.  I am hoping I can give the client a cms backend to input the text that appears in the marker points on a map.  What I am trying with no success is:

```
var point = new GLatLng(49.295308,-123.149297);
var marker = createMarker(point,"Site Title",'<div class="maptext"><p class="prepend-top caption">Title<\/p>

    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query('category_name=featured');
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();?>
    <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'site-description', true) ) { ?>
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'site-description', $single = true); ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <\/div>')
          map.addOverlay(marker);
```

ok sarfaz was right with his orignal response and I was getting a parse error which was breaking it.   what finally worked was this:

```
 var point = new GLatLng(48.134239,-122.764769);
      var marker = createMarker(point,"Port Townsend Marine Science Center",'<div class="maptext"><?php $the_query = new WP_Query('post_name=test-site');
while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();?><?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'map-content', true) ) { ?><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "map-content", $single = true); ?><?php } ?><?php endwhile; ?><\/div>')
      map.addOverlay(marker);
```

--- UPDATE ---

Just wanted to add that I found this to be the best way for me to grab posts since I always want a specific one linked to that marker :

```
  var point = new GLatLng(48.5139,-123.150531);
  var marker = createMarker(point,"Lime Kiln State Park", 
    '<?php $post_id = 182;
$my_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $my_post->post_title;
echo $title;
echo $my_post->post_content;
?>')
      map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Comment: Post the generated source code too; there's probably an error in your JS.

Comment: no error in the js, at least according to firebug, and the map works great until i try injecting this php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Yes, that is surely possible to have php echoed in javascript code. In your code you are missing the `endwhile` so only first subsequent line of your code is executing causing you unexpected result.</strike>

**Update:** Try t his:

```
var point = new GLatLng(49.295308,-123.149297);
var marker = createMarker(point,"Site Title","<div class=\"maptext\"><p class=\"prepend-top caption\">Title</p>

    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query('category_name=featured');
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();?>
    <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'site-description', true) ) { ?>
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'site-description', $single = true); ?>

    </div>")
          map.addOverlay(marker);
    ..................
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but escaping the quotes does not help.  I have been trying many variations including stripping out all of the css to see if it helps but nothing seems to be working

Comment: ahh you were right the first time. it was just a parse error in the php.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem simply comes from the new lines you generate in the javascript string. 
The output of the code will be something like this:

```
var marker = createMarker(point,"Site Title","<div class="\maptext\"><p class=\"prepend-top caption\">Title</p>
    thedatafromyourquery
    </div>")
```

what you want to have is something like this:

```
var marker = createMarker(point,"Site Title","<div class="\maptext\"><p class=\"prepend-top caption\">Title</p>" +
    "thedatafromyourquery" +
    "</div>")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: would it be possible to post the whole generated source code of the javascript?